# How to encapsulate state function in Svelte like React hook?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am trying to extract state controlling function from a component to an individual component(or function) in Svelte for reuse and decoupling, like React hook.

I tried to encapsulate a counter increment as following, but it doesn't work. Reactivity is lost and the count doesn't increase. How should I extract state controlling function properly in Svelte?

**useIncrement.svelte**

```
<script context="module">
import {onMount} from 'svelte';
function useIncrement(){
  let count = 0;
  onMount(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => count++, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });
  console.log('toggling')
  return count
}

export {
  useIncrement
}
</script>
```

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
  import { useIncrement } from './useToggle.svelte'
  import {onMount} from 'svelte';
  let count = useIncrement()
</script>

<div class="App">
    <p>Page has been open for <code>{count}</code> seconds.</
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

In situations like this, where you want to reuse functionality in different Svelte components and encapsulate that in a function, write that function in a regular JavaScript file and use a store:

**useIncrement.js**

```js
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

export function useIncrement(){
  let count = writable(0); // <- wrap count in a store
  onMount(() => {
    // instead of count++, use the store's update function:
    const interval = setInterval(() => count.update(c => c + 1), 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });
  return count;
}
```

In this specific case, the code can be simplified by using a readable store and removing the `onMount`:

**useIncrement.js**

```js
import { readable } from 'svelte/store';

export function useIncrement() {
  let count = 0;
  return readable(count, set => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => set(++count), 1000);
    // Will be called on unsubscribe:
    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  });
}
```

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
  import { useIncrement } from './useIncrement'
  let count = useIncrement()
</script>

<div class="App">
    <!-- subscribe to the store by prepending $ to the variable -->
    <p>Page has been open for <code>{$count}</code> seconds.
</div>
```

The reason why you can't use regular variable reassignments (`x = y`) inside `useIncrement.js` is that Svelte will work its magic of reflecting updates of a variable in the view only if that reassignment happens within its own components. You never assign a new value to `count` in `App.svelte`, which is why it does not work in your code snippet. Also, Svelte will not apply special logic to regular JavaScript files. That's why you need to wrap the counter in a store and subscribe to its changes.

Docs on stores: https://svelte.dev/docs#svelte_store

Comment: I believe it is better to return a readable store here, that would not require importing the onMount function in a non-component.  (also the code looks suspiciously exactly like the use case in the docs for readable stores.

Comment: I was trying to be as close as possible to the question's code snippet. But you are right, a readable store fits better in this case. I'll update with another code snippet.